# SQL get chat query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-string

I have this query in sql, and i can't get it right.

I'm trying to make a query to get the results from chat.

```
select message, first_name, last_name, dataPost,picture 
from chat_comms 
right join utilizadores 
           on (chat_comms.id_writer = utilizadores.id_user) 
               or (chat_comms.id_reader =  utilizadores.id_user) 
where id_writer = 1 
or (id_reader = 1 and id_writer = 13) 
order by dataPost ASC
```

**RESULT**

[image]

the **first_name, last_name, picture**, should be different because they are different users, how can i solve this?

---

**SQL FIDDLE:**

**[VIEW SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d336bf/3)**

---

Comment: With out knowing about the data in tables. My guess is in your join condition you have `OR` with other conditions, try replacing it with `AND`

Comment: for me to replace for AND i have to change to left join wich is no problem, but that dont return any data from the users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the duplicate rows because one of the users is the "writer" and the other is the "reader". I'm guessing that you actually want one row for each row in `chat_comms` linked to both the "writer" and "reader". In this case you need to join to `utilizadores` twice instead of using the `or`:

```
select message, writer.first_name, writer.last_name, dataPost, picture 
from chat_comms 
left join utilizadores writer on chat_comms.id_writer = writer.id_user
left join utilizadores reader on chat_comms.id_reader = reader.id_user
where id_writer = 1 
or (id_reader = 1 and id_writer = 13) 
order by dataPost ASC
```

This is just a guess because you haven't adequately described the result you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

please verify below mentioned query:

```
SELECT message, first_name, last_name, dataPost,picture
FROM chat_comms
RIGHT JOIN utilizadores
       ON chat_comms.id_writer = utilizadores.id_user
       OR (chat_comms.id_reader =  utilizadores.id_user)
WHERE id_writer = 1
order by dataPost ASC
```

Hope that helps, thanks.